# How to fix "KeyboardAvoidingView" in IOS when use Native Base Content structure

Tags: react-native, expo, native-base

I use the KeyboardAvoidingView, to display the input focused, but when the KeyBoard is showing, the scrollView paddingBottom changes and overlaps the Form.

```
<Container style={styles.container}>
  <Content contentContainerStyle={{flex:1}} scrollEnabled={false} enableOnAndroid  >{/* styles.content */}
    <ScrollView style={{flex: 1}} automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={true} indicatorStyle="white" >
      <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding" enabled={Platform.OS === 'android' ? true : false} style={styles.keyboardAvoidingView} keyboardVerticalOffset={60} >
        <Form style={{margin:20,marginRight:35}}>
          <Input>
            {/*... Some Inputs*/}
          </Input>
        </Form>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    </ScrollView>
  </Content>
</Container>
```

Image 1:
[image]

Image 2: 
[image]

Image 3: 
[image]

Comment: you can use `keyboard-aware-scroll-view` https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view

Comment: the bug persists, because I use Native Base, and the "Content" component use React Native Keyboard Aware Scroll View (But this not work with Android)